# incrementing on errors

Tags: postgresql

How do I suppress the 'id' in this table from incrementing when an error occurs?

```
db=> CREATE TABLE test (id serial primary key, info text, UNIQUE(info));
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "test_id_seq" for serial column "test.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "test_pkey" for table "test"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / UNIQUE will create implicit index "test_info_key" for table "test"
CREATE TABLE

db=> INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ('hello') ;
INSERT 0 1

db=> INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ('hello') ;
ERROR:  duplicate key violates unique constraint "test_info_key"

db=> INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ('hello') ;
ERROR:  duplicate key violates unique constraint "test_info_key"

db=> INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ('goodbye') ;
INSERT 0 1

db=> SELECT * from test; SELECT last_value from test_id_seq;

 id |  info   
----+---------
  1 | hello
  4 | goodbye
(2 rows)

 last_value 
------------
          4
(1 row)
```

Comment: Could you explain why this is a problem for you?

Comment: I noticed the jump in the id sequence when I was dumping a smaller remote database into a larger master database.  There are several remote databases that I need to culminate.Originally I omitted the 'id' in the table layout and relied solely

Comment: ...Originally I omitted the 'id' in the table layout and relied solely on the UNIQUE key value.  This prevented creating duplicate rows when inserting the same rows over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I needed to write a wrapper function around my INSERT statement.

The database will normally have one user at a time so the 'race to the next id' condition is rare.  What I was concerned about was when my (unmentioned) 'pull rows from remote database table' function would try to reinsert the growing remote database table into the master database table.  I am displaying the row ids and I didn't want the users to see the gap in numbering as missing data.

Anyways here is my solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION testInsert (test.info%TYPE) RETURNS void AS '
BEGIN
  PERFORM info FROM test WHERE info=$1;
  IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO test (info) VALUES ($1);
  END IF;
END;' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot suppress this - and there is nothing wrong with having gaps in your ID values.

The primary key is a totally meaningless value that is only used to uniquely identify one row in a table.

You cannot rely on the ID to never have any gaps - just think what happens if you delete a row.

Simply ignore it - nothing is wrong

**Edit**
Just wanted to mention that this behaviour is also clearly stated in the manual:

> *To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back*

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html
(Scroll to the bottom)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I was perceiving the INSERT statement as an atomic transaction that would increment on successful insert.

Comment: @John Wasinger: the INSERT itself **is** atomic, only the generation of sequence numbers is non-transactional and therefor not atomic (btw: this is the same in all DBMS that support sequences)

Answer (score 2):

Your question boils down to this: "Can I rollback the next value from a PostgreSQL sequence?"

And the answer is, "You can't." PostgreSQL documentation says

[To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back . . .](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine two different transactions go to insert.  Transaction A gets id=1 Transaction B gets id=2.  Transaction B commits.  transaction A rolls back.  Now what do we do?  How could we roll back the sequence for A without affecting B or later transactions?

Comment: +1 for a VERY good illustration of one of the reasons why sequences aren't rolled back and why one should never insist/rely on a "gapless" sequence.